# How to think of a set that has "no accumulation point"?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is there a basic or intutive way to think of a set which does not have any accumulation set. The related question [Is a set closed if it has no accumulation points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991190/is-a-set-closed-if-it-has-no-accumulation-points) does give some insight but it seems, it still does not answer the question at hand. Any comments would be appreciated.

Edit: More specifically what one should infer from the condition:
" a subset $A$ of $R$ that is bounded from below has no accumulation point".

EDIT: The above statment is taken from:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_structure

Comment: The statement in the last paragraph is false: take $A=[0,1]$, which is full of accumulation points.

Comment: @GregMartin A just added a link, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's not a statement (in that link), that's a *condition*. A regular structure is a triple $(A,T,G)$ where $A$ is a set bounded from below without accumulation points. It's **not** saying all such sets have no accumulation points...

Comment: Admittedly, the linked statement is grammatically incorrect for being a condition and looks exactly like an assertion would look. The word "and" should be inserted after "below".

Comment: @GregMartin, yes a very good point, I edit the word statment to condition, thanks.

Comment: Well, for Euclidean $\mathbb R$ any open interval will have all points in it as accumulation points so a set with none woud be a set of singletons.   In Euclidean $\mathbb R^k$ any set in a block will be accumulation points but segments with no width will not be.  ... So *intuitively* a set with no accumulation points is one with no areas of "thinkness".  ... But I doubt that really helps as topo spaces can be so diffferent and unintutive.It's easier to just use definition and not have intuition.

Comment: @fleablood, thank you for your comments, is it possbile to know why this condition is there in the regularity structure definition?

Comment: Similar question now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370484/when-and-why-do-we-require-the-condition-that-a-subset-bounded-from-below-and

Comment: @GerryMyerson i mentioned this question in MO.

Comment: Yes, Creator, you did, and that was good. But you didn't mention the MO question here, so I did it for you.